# Result code 7002 is returned when I try to save/load the game progress

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

Game progress is saved and loaded correctly only 5-7 times. Then when I try to save/load I get error code 7002. After 3-5 minutes of waiting, saving / loading works correctly, but again only 5-7 times. Then the problem repeats.

Internet connection is stable. Can anyone help?
Logs:

HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: api is: game.resolveConflict, resolution: null, status_code: 1

HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:1, error_code:7002, api_name:game.resolveConflict, app_id:*******|, pkg_name: ***.*****.******.huawei, session_id:*, transaction_id:*******nflict***********, resolution:null

Comment: hi@Henokean, Could you pls provide more detail logs to help us trace this issue？

Comment: @shirley 
HMSSDK_BaseAdapter: api is: game.resolveConflict, resolution: null, status_code: 1

HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:1, error_code:7002, api_name:game.resolveConflict, app_id:*********|, pkg_name:***.******.******.huawei, session_id:*, transaction_id:*******nflict***********, resolution:null

Answer (score 0):

Error code 7002 means Network Error. See: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/guide-error-0000001050994619
[image]

And this information is in line with your issue symptoms. For further investigation, please provide error log.

Comment: There are no error logs. I get only result code 7002. Internet connection is stable and the settings on AppGallery seems to be ok. As far as I understand, if the settings were incorrect, then saving / updating / loading would not work at all.
It works but not as expected.